# Ошибка 405 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/& 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

Подскажите пожалуйста я в этом новичёк. Пытаюсь сделать добавление комментариев без перезагрузки страницы через ajax, но ничего не получается, может я что то упускаю.

**//blade**

```html
 <form id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="return sendForm();">
                                    <textarea name="message"  class="textarea" rows="3"
                                              placeholder="Напишите свой комментарий"></textarea>
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary comment-button" id="saveBtn">Comment</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

**//script**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#saveBtn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            sendForm();
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#saveBtn').html('Отправить');
        //Отправка на сервер данных
        $('.error-message').html();

        function sendForm() {
            var formI = $('#ajaxForm')[0];

            var form = new FormData(formI);

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url("/posts/' + slug + '/comments")}}',
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {form},

                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.success)
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    // if (error) {
                    //     console.log(error.responseJSON.errors.message)
                    //     $('#errorMessage').html(error.responseJSON.errors.message);
                    // }
                },
            });

            return false;
        }


    });
```

**//route**

```html
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Post', 'prefix' => 'posts'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Post\IndexController::class, 'index'])->name('post.index');
    Route::get('/{slug}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Post\ShowController::class, 'index'])->name('post.show');

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Comment', 'prefix' => '{slug}/comments'], function (){
        Route::post('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Post\Comment\StoreController::class, 'index'])->name('post.comment.store');
    });

});
```

**//StoreController**

```html
 public function index(Post $post, StoreRequest $request)
    {

        $data = $request->validated();
        $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $data['commentable_id'] = $post->id;
        Comment::create($data);

    }
```

[image: 405]

[image: 405]

[image: Ошибка в контроллере]

[image: Ошибка в контроллере]

Comment: Ну, посмотрите на ошибку и сам роут в ошибке, который выглядит таким образом `posts/&`

Comment: Но у меня нет вариантов почему так происходит, понятно что маршрут не правильный, всё дело в маршруте?  url: '{{ url("/posts/' + slug + '/comments")}}',

Comment: Эта строка `url: '{{ url("/posts/' + slug + '/comments")}}',` у Вас в JS файле? И что-то я не виду откуда там `slug` берется вообще.

Comment: Да этот скрипт находиться в main.blade.html. Всё верно, вот тут я и не понимаю. Я понимаю что slug это и есть ID поста, но я видать не до конца понимаю как работает slug.

Comment: `slug` -- это slug и он не является ID поста

Comment: Получается, что при запросе необходимо так же добавлять ID поста верно? Я нашёл одну статью подобную и внёс изменения в свой код, вроде логика понятная но теперь другая ошибка:  Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined.   url: '/posts/' + id + '-' + slug + '/comments/', а это в роут вписал:  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Comment', 'prefix' => '{id}-{slug?}/comments'], function (){

Comment: 1. Зачем Вы передаете в запросе slug? Вы с ним ничего не делаете в принципе. 2. Раз Вы работаете с JS переменными, то они где-то должны быть определены.

Comment: Понял. Вот я инициализировал переменную var id = '$post->id';  и поменял url: '/posts/' + id + '/comments/', вроде логика есть и опять ошибка повяляется: jquery.min.js:2 
 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/$post-%3Eid/comments/ 422 (Unprocessable Content) и вот этот вот странный маршрут $post-%3Eid, почему они именно так формируеться?

Comment: JS не будет работать с PHP переменными, как и PHP, в Вашем случае Blade не будет работать с JS переменными, это разные ЯП, Вам бы для начала с базовыми вещами разобраться, до работы с Laravel. Если хотите заставить работать это чудо, то попробуйте вот так `var id = '{{ $post->id }}'`. А по поводу странного маршрута, потому что символ стрелки был кодирован, так как в URL разрешено использовать только определенный набор символов. Любой символ, который не входит в этот набор, должен быть заменён на процент (%) за которым следуют две шестнадцатеричные цифры, представляющие ASCII-код символа.

Comment: Для отладки своего JS используйте `console.log()`.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но я так уже пробовал var id = '{{ $post->id }}' вот так:  var postId = '{{ $slug }}'; var commentContent = '{{ $comment->message }}'; var userId = '{{ $comment->user_id }}'; и он вносит данные в бд, кроме комментария, потому что вместо него он пишет это: {{ $comment->message }}

Comment: Дебажте, вносит в таком виде не просто так, значит что-то Вы делаете не правильно.

Comment: Вроде заработало, но есть непонятные моменты  для меня почему оно работает, как будто это магия...

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время.

Comment: Разберетесь во всем и понимание придет, такое ощущение из-за недостатка опыта)

Comment: Так я в этом новичёк, поэтому и обращаюсь к тем, кто в этом разбирается. А опыт без реальных проектов не наберёшь... Вот и учусь, разными способами, что то понимаю, а что то нет.